# invoke method with list of parameter c#

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

I have a class:

namespace TestLib1

```
public class TestLib1
{
    public IEnumerable<TestedParameter> Measure1(IEnumerable<TestedParameter> _inParameters)
    { // this is just to do something
        foreach (TestedParameter item in _inParameters)
        {
            item.Param_Description = "TestParam";
        }
        return _inParameters;
    }
}
```

that contains class from

```
public class Acceptance_Criteria
{
    private double _lowest;
    private double _highest;
    public bool Compare(double _verifiedValue)
    {
        if ((_verifiedValue >= _lowest) && (_verifiedValue <= _highest))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }        
    public double Acceptance_Lowest { get =>_lowest;set =>_lowest = value; }
    public double Acceptance_Highest {get=>_highest;set =>_highest = value; }
}
  
public class TestedParameter : Acceptance_Criteria
{
    private string _param_Description;
    private double _value;
    private string _units;
    private bool _value_matches_acceptance_critera;
    private bool _value_checked_against_criteria;
    private string pass_fail_reason;
    public string Param_Description { get => _param_Description; set => _param_Description = value; }
    public double Value { get => _value; set => _value = value; }
    public string Units { get => _units; set => _units = value; }
    public bool Value_matches_acceptance_critera { get => _value_matches_acceptance_critera; set => _value_matches_acceptance_critera = value; }
    public bool Value_checked_against_criteria { get => _value_checked_against_criteria; set => _value_checked_against_criteria = value; }
    public string Pass_fail_reason { get => pass_fail_reason; set => pass_fail_reason = value; }
}
```

and I placed TestLib in DLL and call it from other file :

```
Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("TestLib1.dll");  
Type[] types2 = SampleAssembly.GetTypes();//e



        Type SearchedType = null;
        foreach (Type type in types2)
        {
            if (type.FullName.Contains("TestLib1.TestLib1")) { SearchedType = SampleAssembly.GetType(type.FullName); }
        }


        if (SearchedType != null)
        {
            MethodInfo Method = SearchedType.GetMethod("Measure1");
            if (Method != null)
            {
                object result = null;
                ParameterInfo[] parameters = Method.GetParameters();
                object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(SearchedType, null);
                if (parameters.Length == 0)
                {
                    //This works fine
                    result = Method.Invoke(classInstance, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    List<TestedParameter> parametersIn = new List<TestedParameter>();
                    TestedParameter param1 = new TestedParameter();
                    param1.Param_Description = "testparam1";             // GET NAME FROM XML
                    parametersIn.Add(param1);

                    IEnumerable<TestedParameter> enumarableList = parametersIn.AsEnumerable();

                    object[] parametersArrayx = new object[] { enumarableList };
                    object resx = Method.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArrayx.ToArray());
                    List<TestedParameter> res = (List<TestedParameter>)resx;
                }
            }



        }
```

When I execute Method.Invoke
I get thie exception:

> System.ArgumentException:
>
> 'Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WindowsFormsApp1.TestedParameter]'
> cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WindowsFormsApp1.TestedParameter]'.'

I also tried to push parametersArrayx without ToArray() but it also didnt work

Can anyone look a the code a let me know what do I do wrong ?
I want to execute code from DLL lib with list of parameters pushed (later I want to import those parameters from XML file.)

Thank You :)

Comment: in which assembly in `TestedParameter` declared ? This looks like you have loaded the same assembly twice.

Comment: Why not add a simple reference to `TestLib1` in your main project? Then you don't have to mess with `Assembly.LoadFrom()`. Or if you need TestLib1 to stay separate from the main solution, investigate turning TestLib1 into a NuGet package.

Comment: Yes I looked ath the same solution and when I exchanged enumarableList to parametersIn it gives the same exception

Comment: Why not add a simple reference to TestLib1 in your main project?  I wanted to have flexibility for future to add DLLs with XML reconfigurable test parameters and functoin names not to recompile whole project. This will allow someone else to create test sequences and upload only DLL and XML for that purpose. Or am I doing it wrong way ? NuGet package hmmm I feel thin in this topic :( yet

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchedType.GetMethod("Measure1");
```

convert to

```
   SearchedType.GetMethod("Measure1", new Type[] { typeof(List<Filter>) });
```